# Swift : Program for addition of 2 numbers using closure

Tags: swift

```
let fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileName, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileName)!

guard let number1 = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let number2 = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)

fileHandle.write(String(res).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

This is given question. Want the addition sum in res, so that res can be printed. I'm new to swift. Kindly help. What is the extra code to be written without modifying the question?

Have tried following solutions :

```
if let res = closure(number1: number1, number2: number2){
    return number1+number2
}
```

and:

```
func closure(number1: Int, number2: Int) -> Int {
    return number1 + number2
}
```

Getting the following errors:

```
solution.swift:23:11: error: expected initial value after '='
let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
          ^
solution.swift:23:10: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
         ^
         ;
solution.swift:23:22: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
                     ^
                     ;
solution.swift:23:15: error: type annotation missing in pattern
let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
              ^
solution.swift:23:22: warning: expression of type '(number1: Int, number2: Int)' is unused
let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: yes, have checked so many links too.

Comment: Well show us what you've tried, what you've read, what error messages, came up, etc.

Comment: the main problem i'm unable to understand is closure is defined as immutable but with method returns.. here in the question i cant again define closure.

Comment: have tried this too ::

Comment: You need to show your implementation of `closure`.

Comment: @swetasrinivas Please do not post details in comments. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant details.

Comment: And please read the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: @maddy read and tried all the possible answers i could.

Comment: `let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)`. Just change this line to `let res = closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)`. The 2nd `let` is redundant!

Answer (score 3):

Closures are really simple in Swift. Here is an example Closure for adding two numbers:

```
let closure:((Int, Int) -> Int) = { (number1, number2) in
    return number1 + number2
}
```

Just like with normal variables you set the type of a closure after a colon. In this case it's:

```
((Int, Int) -> Int)
```

which means: Take two Ints as parameters and return a Int.

Usage:

```
let firstNumber = 5
let secondNumber = 6

let additionResult = closure(firstNumber, secondNumber)
//additionResult is 11
```

In your specific use case:

```
let closure:((Int, Int) -> Int) = { (number1, number2) in
    return number1 + number2
}

let fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileName, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileName)!

guard let number1 = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

guard let number2 = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }

let res = closure(number1, number2)

fileHandle.write(String(res).data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Comment: let res = let closure(number1: number1, number2: number2) 
question has this statement given, where error is coming

Comment: Look at my answer. I wrote for you the usage of a closure. Simply try it like it is shown in my answer and it will work

Comment: the question cant be edited. will have to write extra lines of code without altering the question.

Comment: Because I don't know, how you implement the closure, I can only say, how I would do it

Answer (score 2):

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.
>
> Closures can capture and store references to any constants and variables from the context in which they are defined. This is known as closing over those constants and variables. Swift handles all of the memory management of capturing for you.
>
> Reference: [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)

**Example:**

For sorting you can define a simple function, and to pass it in as an argument to the `sorted(by:)` method:

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]

func backward(_ s1: String, _ s2: String) -> Bool {
    return s1 > s2
}

var reversedNames = names.sorted(by: backward)
// reversedNames is equal to ["Ewa", "Daniella", "Chris", "Barry", "Alex"]
```

Rather than using a function you can write closure for that, as:

```
var reversedNames = names.sorted(by: { (s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool in
    return s1 > s2
})
```

**Solution for your problem:**

Either you write and use:

```
func closure(number1: Int, number2: Int) {
    return number1 + number2
}

let res = closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
```

Or, you can implement:

```
let closure:((Int, Int) -> Int) = { (number1, number2) in return number1 + number2 }

let res = closure(number1: number1, number2: number2)
```